# How do I copy multiple files in another directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, copy

I have a dataset including images in ascending order, like `images_0001.png`, `images_0002.png` ... `images_0500.png` and so on. I want to copy specific range of this images into another directory. For example, 100 images will be copied between `images_0210.png` to `images_0310.png`. Does anybody have any idea how to do that?

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I am sorry if I did violated how to ask policy. I am in learning process and developing myself day by day. Thank you for your feedbacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import shutil
import os

start_idx = 210
num_of_files = 100
source_path = "source/path/dir"
dest_path = "dest/path/dir"

for idx in range(start_idx, start_idx + num_of_files):
    src_file_path = os.path.join(source_path, f"images_{idx:04d}.png")
    if os.access(src_file_path, os.R_OK):
        shutil.copy(src_file_path, dest_path)
    else:
        print(f"The file {src_file_path} is not readable")
```

where `{idx:04d}` is a 4 characters representation of the file index (for example, if the index is 12 it will be 0012)